# Vue library component error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue-bayt-ui' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I'm trying to create a library for Vue component with typescript using vite. However when I try to use it I am getting the error `Vue library component error TS2307: Cannot find module 'vue-bayt-ui' or its corresponding type declarations.`

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "vue-bayt-ui",
    "private": false,
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "type": "module",
    "files": [
        "dist",
        "src/components"
    ],
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "import": {
                "types": "./types/esm/index.d.ts",
                "default": "./esm/vue-bayt-ui.js"
            },
            "require": {
                "types": "./types/commonjs/index.d.cts",
                "default": "./commonjs/vue-bayt-ui.cjs"
            }
        }
    },
    "types": "./types/index.d.ts",
    "main": "./commonjs/vue-bayt-ui.cjs",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
        "types": "vue-tsc ",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.3.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "vite": "^5.0.8",
        "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.6.4",
        "vue-tsc": "^1.8.25"
    }
}
```

I tried many other things. And read a lot of tutorials and I am getting this error even on those who have tutorials. Such as this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-and-publish-a-vue-component-library-update/

This is how I try to use my library
import {VButton} from 'vue-bayt-ui'